# generate csv file force close android

Tags: android

I am generating csv file and it force close, why?
my code is

```
   package contactlist.pkg;

       import java.io.FileWriter;
       import java.io.IOException;

     public class GenerateCsv
   {
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
   generateCsvFile("C:\\test.csv"); 
 }

   private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName)
   {
 try
  {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

    writer.append("DisplayName");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("Age");
    writer.append('\n');

    writer.append("MKYONG");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("26");
        writer.append('\n');

    writer.append("YOUR NAME");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("29");
    writer.append('\n');

    //generate whatever data you want

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
} 
   }
}
```

errors are

```
   07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{contactlist.pkg/contactlist.pkg.GenerateCsv}: java.lang.ClassCastException: contactlist.pkg.GenerateCsv
   07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
    07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
      07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
      07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
         07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
           07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: contactlist.pkg.GenerateCsv
         07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
       07-27 13:12:30.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Comment: I don't know Android at all, but I can't imagine that there is a `C:` drive you could access.

Comment: if i change it to "E:\\test.csv" then also crashes

Comment: Oh dear. Why are you trying to use Windows file paths on an Android device?

Comment: try this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` this will return path to android SD Card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package contactlist.pkg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String dir = "/Android/data/contactlist.pkg/csv/";
        String fullDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + dir;
        generateCsvFile(fullDir, "data.csv");
    }

    private static void generateCsvFile(String dir, String fileName) {
        try {

            File theDir = new File(dir);
            theDir.mkdirs();

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(dir + fileName);

            writer.append("DisplayName");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("Age");
            writer.append('\n');

            writer.append("MKYONG");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("26");
            writer.append('\n');

            writer.append("YOUR NAME");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("29");
            writer.append('\n');

            //generate whatever data you want

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("file", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

`String dir = "/Android/data/contactlist.pkg/csv/";` is just and example of how you should structure your application folder in the external storage, it should be like this: `/Android/data/<package_name>/files/`, and you will need to add the permission on the AndroidManifest.xml, directly in `manifest` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I humbly suggest you to read this [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) documentation :)

Comment: hello ayublin ..how to save csv file (test.csv) on "assets"  android folder

Comment: it can't be done, it's packaged on the application.

Comment: I have give the concrete example as a MainActivity, String dir= "/Android/data/com.bla.apps/csv/"; is the path after the SD Card path.

Comment: Open DDMS at your android SDK tools path `android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat`, in DDMS you can open file explorer at `Device->File Explorer` menu, and go into `mnt\sdcard\android\data\..`

Comment: 07-27 14:36:44.908: when i run this information comes on log cat  INFO/file(2626): /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/contactlist.pkg/data.csv (Permission denied) and when i go to DDMS   mnt\sdcard  then there is no content inside sdcard it...how can i check it in emulator?

Comment: Have you added the uses-permission as I described above in you AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes i added it...but i think in  emulator sdcard is not available so what should be the path for getting android emulator memory?

Comment: can you pls check this code on your system pls.and check it..where i am wrong..

Comment: @saurabhtrivedi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1872/discussion-between-ayublin-and-saurabh-trivedi)

Comment: pls upvote my  qus. bcoz my account banned for asking qus .thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: contactlist.pkg.GenerateCsv

In android, you don't have a `main` method, instead, you implement an activity, service or receiver and override some of its methods (such as `onCreate()`). Please refer to the basic android tutorial: [Hello world](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn more about the file structure in Android. There is no C: drive only sdcard to which you write. Use getExternalStorageDirectory to get the correct file path and then do not forget to add WRITE_SDCARD permission.